# How can I run a script in Rosetta from terminal on M1 Mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

How can I run a shell/bash/zsh script in Rosetta from Terminal without having the Terminal being opened in Rosetta?

Answer (score 9):

The `arch` command is useful for that purpose

```
arch -arch_name binary args ...
```

See `man arch` for more details

**Example without rosetta:**

```
echo "arch" > build.sh
arch -arm64 /bin/bash ./build.sh
```

Output:

```
arm64
```

**Example with rosetta:**

```
echo "arch" > build.sh
arch -x86_64 /bin/bash ./build.sh
```

Output:

```
i386
```